# What is URL for SFDC Knowledge Icon?

Tags: visualforce

I want  to include SFDC Knowledge Icon on VisualForce Page .
Some of the icons URLs could be found [HERE](http://free-121d5f44d20-121d603d1c5-121ee2b8103.force.com/force2b/salesforceicons)
But URL knowledge Icon is not specified here.
Whats the URL for Knowledge Icon?

Comment: is you want http://www.salesforce.com/crm/customer-service-support/knowledge-base-system/ icon? if it is not available then you have to download and add it to static resources, from there then you can access it on VF page

Answer (score 8):

To see the tabs, you need the 'Knowledge User' permission after enabling Knowledge itself. This avails the 'Articles' and 'Article Management' tabs, then we can find the icons living in their own folder:

1. Knowledge icon:

   - [/img/knowledge/knowledge16.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/knowledge16.png) (16px) [image: knowledge128]
   - [/img/knowledge/knowledge24.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/knowledge24.png) (24px) [image: knowledge128]
   - [/img/knowledge/knowledge32.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/knowledge32.png) (32px) [image: knowledge128]
   - [/img/knowledge/knowledge64.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/knowledge64.png) (64px) [image: knowledge128]
2. Knowledge management icon

   - [/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement16.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement16.png) (16px) [image: knowledge128]
   - [/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement24.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement24.png) (24px) [image: knowledge128]
   - [/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement32.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement32.png) (32px) [image: knowledge128]
   - [/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement64.png](https://login.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/publishing/knowledgemanagement64.png) (64px) [image: knowledge128]

Comment: sorry I posted in same time

Comment: @brovasi you made a great point on using the static resource, if salesforce move the icons

Answer (score 2):

Something like: 
https://cs5.salesforce.com/img/knowledge/knowledge24.png

but I would advice you to upload the image as a static resource